# Postgres 9.6 update jsonb column to add new attribute with a value from query

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table xyz, with a metadata jsonb column in postgres.
`Table : xyz
 column : metadata, type = jsonb`

```
metadata = {"exceptions": {"first_exception": "first_value"} }
```

I want to add a new `sub_attribute`

```
desired metadata = {"exceptions": {"first_exception": "123"},{"second_exception": "234"}  }
```

I can use the

```
update xyz 
SET metadata = jsonb_set(metadata->'exceptions', '{second_exception}', '"234"', true).
```

But I want to get the value `234` from a select query. I am not able to figure how to combine the select query with the update to do this.

Comment: to facilitate a bit, could add the create table statements?

Comment: I add the structure. I just want to know how to use query's output as a value for the new attribute to be added

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
UPDATE xyz
SET metadata = jsonb_set(metadata, '{exceptions, second_exception}', other.value::jsonb)
FROM other
WHERE other.column = xyz.column
```

Pay attention that `{"exceptions": {"first_exception": "123"},{"second_exception": "234"}}` is not a valid json and update will give you following result `{"exceptions": {"first_exception": "123", "second_exception": "234"}}`